# Vim: gf with file extension based on current FileType

Tags: vim

I'm trying to set up my `.vimrc` so `gf` will automatically work on paths that are missing file extensions, by trying to open files with the same extension as the current FileType.

In other words, I want something like:

```
autocmd FileType <filetype> setl suffixesadd+=<exts>
```

where `<exts>` is a list of all file extensions associated with the current `<filetype>`.

For example, my `filetype.vim` defines the FileType "javascript" as files with names `*.js`,`*.javascript`,`*.es`,`*.jsx`, and `*.json`, so whenever I am editing a javascript buffer, if the cursor is on the path `./index`, running `gf` should try to open `./index.js`. If that file doesn't exist then it should try `./index.javascript`, and so on. If the filetype is python, it should try `./index.py`, `./index.pyw`, etc.

I'm pretty sure the autocmd above should produce the intended behavior if I just run it for every FileType, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: What's wrong with the autocommand you wrote?

Comment: Did you package this as a vim plugin? ...."I'll use it in conjunction with an autocmd that adds the current file extension to suffixesadd" -- sounds like a great idea.

Comment: @alexanderbird I was mainly using this for jumping to files in NodeJs `require` statements, and realized that matching _every_ extension for a filetype isn't that useful in practice. Now I just use this one autocmd to add the current file extension: `autocmd BufRead * execute 'setl suffixesadd+=.' . expand('%:e')`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those default extensions are not stored anywhere in a useful format so you will need to build your own list and loop through it to run your autocommand.

Something like:

```
augroup suffixes
    autocmd!

    let associations = [
                \["javascript", ".js,.javascript,.es,.esx,.json"],
                \["python", ".py,.pyw"]
                \]

    for ft in associations
        execute "autocmd FileType " . ft[0] . " setlocal suffixesadd=" . ft[1]
    endfor
augroup END
```

Comment: That's disappointing to hear. Thanks for your answer, I'll use it in conjunction with an autocmd that adds the current file extension to `suffixesadd`.